# I can't execute command 'electroshot' installed with npm in a django app served in IIS

Tags: django, python-3.x, iis-8

I want to execute 'electroshot' command, is for creating pdf from a html, the problem is when the django app is serve on IIS give me following error:

**'electroshot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Serving the app with django runserver works correctly.

Here is the code when i execute the command:

```
filename = "file.html" 

fScript = r"""electroshot file://{0} 1920x1024 --format pdf --pdf-background""".format(filename)

subprocess.Popen(fScript, stdout=open("myoutput","w"), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, shell=True)
```

I send the stdout to a file to check the error,that is **'electroshot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I have LocalSystem in ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Comment: Then have you installed NPM and install the tool? https://github.com/mixu/electroshot

Comment: @LexLi yes, i have all installed, i solve the problem changing the permissions of the  npm folder, and restart the server.